# SOAP client или запрос curl'ом, что лучше?

Tags: php, curl, soap

Всем привет, давно работает парсилка информации от почты России через `SoapClient`, частенько запросы висят, сейчас думаем использовать библиотечку для парсинга, которая под капотом сама формирует запросы и отправляет данные через curl.

Собственно вопрос в следующем - стоит ли овчинка выделки? Возможно нативный `SoapClient` лучше подходит для этих целей?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, разве что только менять протокол.